# How to run a block of code in the background in android?

Tags: android, multithreading, performance

I am trying to make an application that loads the contact list from the phone but this takes a lot of time based on the number of contacts. I want to run load the contact list in the background so that it does not slow down the application. 
I am using the following function to load the contact information.

```
void loadContacts() {
    ContentResolver contentResolver=getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor=contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI,null,null,null,null);
    if(cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            Bitmap photo = retrieveContactPhoto(id);
            int hasPhoneNumber = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)));
            String phoneNumber = null;
            if (hasPhoneNumber > 0) {
                Cursor cursor2 = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", new String[]{id}, null);
                while (cursor2.moveToNext()) {
                    String ph = cursor2.getString(cursor2.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                    phoneNumber = ph.replaceAll("\\s", "");
                    System.out.println(phoneNumber);
                }
                cursor2.close();
            }
            if(phoneNumber==null)
                continue;
        }
    }
    cursor.close();
}
```

Comment: you can use asyncktask

Comment: `AsyncTask` will let you run stuff on background thread

Comment: Use a `CursorLoader`; it's a much more robust approach than using an `AsyncTask`. See [this tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html), which does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a Loader to get your queries resolved. Using Loaders gives you some benefits. One of them is that: if the user rotates their phone and Activity gets restarted, the loader is preserved (query the database is no more needed, as the reference to your cursor will still be available in the Loader), i.e, loaders are lifecycle aware. You need to implement

```
 LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>
```

like this

```
 MyActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
     LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor>{

        @Override
        public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
                     //return a new instance of CursorLoader

                          return new CursorLoader(this) {
                                   //this reference will be preserved when activity rotates
                                   Cursor myCursor;


                                    @Override
                                   protected void onStartLoading() {
                                        super.onStartLoading();

                                        //myCursor will be null when activity is starting for the first time
                                        if (myCursor== null)
                                                 forceLoad();
                                         else
                                          deliverResult(myCursor);
        }

                                   @Override
                                   public Cursor loadInBackground() {
                                       //make your database query here

                                       myCursor = getContext().getContentResolver().query()
                                         return myCursor;

                                        }

                                 }


                      }

        @Override
      public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {

                       //bind your Cursor to your activity view

                       }


         @Override
         public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {

                       }


          }
```

For more information, checkout my Udacity Nanodegree code [here](https://github.com/blessochampion/PopularMovies/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/popularmovies/popularmovies/activities/PopularMoviesActivity.java)  line 272 - 338 explains it better.

Answer (score 1):

You can use several decisions:

1. AsyncQueryHelper - it is wrapper class for database requests. It is an abstract class, so you must create your own implementation. See this link:
   https://gist.github.com/EugeneShapovalov94/9944560e42a080d35d6ce06fb17e41c4
2. CursorLoader - This is decision based on loaders. You should implement loader callbacks to start it, receive result and reset it. See this link:
   http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2012/07/loaders-and-loadermanager-background.html
3. RxJava - This is the most difficult decision, but it is the most flexible. You can modify observable/single to get different result from the source (filter, map). You should subscribeOn Schedulers.IO and observeOn AndroidSchedulers.mainThead.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways for doing background task.

- `AsyncTask`: old fashioned => [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)
- `Handler`: [post about that](https://blog.mindorks.com/android-core-looper-handler-and-handlerthread-bd54d69fe91a)
- `Thread`: classic (java style)
- `RxJava`: my favorite => [doc](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava)
- ...

Example with `RxJava` (version 2) with `Kotlin`:

```
    Observable
            .fromCallable<String> {
                // Do the job here
                "the result"
            }
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe { result ->
                // use the result!
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple way is to it on worker thread where you should implement `Runnable` interface with logic written in run method.

Else you can also go for AsyncTask for doing this job - [check this link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Answer (score 0):

Anything u write(or)wrote Asynctask class in doInBackground methods inside call ur method runs in the background. It has run different thread no connection UI.

Sample of Async

```
      class MyAsync extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, String>
        {

            protected void onPreExecute (){

            }

            protected String doInBackground(Void...arg0) {
                //do wht need in background
    `            loadContacts();
                return " ";
            }


        }
```

Call it like in your activity:

```
new MyAsync().execute();
```

Comment: Are u try this one

Answer (score 0):

If you used Kotlin with Anko you could do it very easy

```
doAsync {

//code to run in the background

uiThread {

//code to run on the ui ( like changing a text or something )

}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with an Async task like this:

```
private class yourMethod extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    public yourMethod() {

    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get and display your contacts you can use a [`CursorLoader`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html) which

> queries the ContentResolver and returns a Cursor object.

So you will need to implement the [`LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks.html) interface in your own class. You will have to implement as well as the `onCreateLoader` (where you will query the `ContentResolver`), `onLoadFinished` and the `onLoaderReset` methods.
Then you can execute the CursorLoader with the [`getLoaderManager().initLoader(int id, Bundle args, LoaderCallbacks<D> callback);`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/LoaderManager.html#initLoader(int, android.os.Bundle, android.app.LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks)) method.

If you just want to get the contacts without displaying them you can use an [`AsyncTask`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) wich allows you to easly perform background operations.

With the AsyncTask you will need to create an inner class that extends `AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>` the and at least the [`doInBackground(Params... params)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#doInBackground(Params...)) method (where you will write your background code).
You will execute the AsyncTask bt calling `new YourAsyncTask().execute(Params);`.

Answer (score 0):

The Android recommended way to doing this would be by using Asynctask. Code in `doInBackground()` is executed the background. Asynctasks are called by using a private inner class and implementing `doInBackground()` inside it which are then called by using `new YourAsyncTask.execute()`

Another popular way to run code in the background is using RxJava which uses Observables and is very flexible.

It is also possible to make code run in the background using the Thread class